# Create PyQt6 Python Project Executable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller, executable, pyqt6

I code a `Qt` project in `python 3.8` using `PyQt6`. When I run python file by python, no problem. When I try to convert project to executable, it fails. I faced to so many problems and I solved them as looking in google. Howeveri I couldn't find a solution for belove fail.

> This application failed to start because no QT platform plugin could
> be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

I use `auto-py-to-exe` to create executable by belove command

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/output/icon/icon2.ico" --name "Auto Test Repeater" --add-data "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/ScreenCopy;ScreenCopy/"
--add-data "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/ui;ui/" --paths "C:/Users/26010693/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt/bin"
--hidden-import "PyQt6.sip"  "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/ui_main.py"
```

I tried to reinstalling but didn't work. Actually, this problem is common in `PyQt5` and according to Youtube, There is a easy solution to fix it([Youtube Solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lUmS6XhuPLI)) that Copying platform folder(`PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms`) into `Pyqt5-tools` folder, all in `Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages`. However there is no `Pyqt6-tools` folder in `site-packages` and no installation guide on internet.

I need to help to solve it or find another way to create executable compatible for `PyQt6`

Comment: Qt6 has come out recently and the same happens with PyQt6 and PySide6 so I think that the pyinstaller developers have not created the necessary files to support PyQt6 so I recommend you wait and use PyQt5 since at the moment there are no big differences between Qt5 and Qt6

Comment: Did you use a .venv in your application folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying dll files in `Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms`into directly executable output folder is solved the issue. My recent pyinstaller command that:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --windowed --icon "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/output/icon2.ico" --name "Auto Test Player" --add-data "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/ScreenCopy;ScreenCopy/" --add-data "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/ui;ui/" --paths "C:/Users/26010693/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt/bin" --hidden-import "PyQt6.sip" --hidden-import "PyQt6.QtPrintSupport" --add-data "C:/Users/26010693/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt/plugins/platforms;platforms/"  "D:/WorkSpace/Projects/MouseReplayer/ui_main.py"
```

key line to fix is that:

```
--add-data "C:/Users/26010693/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Lib/site-packages/PyQt6/Qt/plugins/platforms;platforms/"
```

and also below line is to prevent another issue:

```
--hidden-import "PyQt6.sip"
```

may be this one also important:

```
--hidden-import "PyQt6.QtPrintSupport"
```